# javascript is not loading my function

Tags: javascript

When the page loads I want it to call a function which does things for me , but JavaScript is not calling the function , and I don't know why. its not giving me any errors but it just won't call function() and how i know that is because when I put document.write before the function i can see "hello" printed on my page . here is the code :

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
   document.write("hello");
er=<? echo $res; ?>;
var res_name = <?php echo json_encode($res_name); ?>;
var res_des = <?php echo json_encode($res_des); ?>;
var res_price = <?php echo json_encode($res_price); ?>;
var errorno = <?php echo json_encode($errorno); ?>;
document.write(res_price);
if(errorno>0){
    alert("Please enter a correct price for item number : "+errorno);
}
for(var p=1;p<=er+1;p++){

var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

var rowCount = table.rows.length;

// create a row element
var row = document.createElement("tr");

// add the row to the table
table.appendChild(row);

var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

// get the select element
var dropdown = row.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
// get the current total of dropdowns in the table
total = (table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length)-1;

if(p==er+1){
  for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
 var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
 //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
        if(i==0){
           newcell.innerHTML =p;
      }else if(i==1){
          newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='name"+p+"' size=30  />";
      }else if(i==2){
          newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='des"+p+"' size=50  />";
      }else if(i==3){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='number' name='price"+p+"'  />";
     }else if(i==4){
           newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='submit' value='Save'  />";
     }

 }
}
else{
    for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
 var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
      if(i==0){
           newcell.innerHTML =p+".";
     }else if(i==1){
          newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='name"+p+"' size=30 value='"+res_name[p]+"' />";
     }else if(i==2){
         newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='des"+p+"' size=50 value='"+res_des[p]+"' />";
     }else if(i==3){
         newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='number' name='price"+p+"' value='"+res_price[p]+"' />";
     }else if(i==4){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='button' name='delete"+p+"' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\","+p+");' />";
     }
 }
}
    document.getElementById('total').value = p;
}
};
  function addRowEntry(tableID ){
     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
 // create a row element
 var row = document.createElement("tr");
     // add the row to the table
 table.appendChild(row);

 var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
 // get the select element
 var dropdown = row.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    // get the current total of dropdowns in the table
    total = (table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length)-1;
 for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
 var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
 //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
    if(i==0){
        newcell.innerHTML =total+".";
    }else if(i==1){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='name"+total+"' size=30  />";
    }else if(i==2){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='text' name='des"+total+"' size=50  />";
    }else if(i==3){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='number' name='price"+total+"'  />";
    }else if(i==4){
        newcell.innerHTML ="<Input type='button' name='delete"+i+"' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\","+i+");' />";
    }
}
document.getElementById('total').value = total;
}
function deleteRow(tableID , po){
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
     table.deleteRow(po);
     document.getElementById('total').value = (document.getElementById('total').value);
     var count = (document.getElementById('total').value)-1 ; 
    for(var o=0 ; o<= count ; o++){

            var x=document.getElementById(tableID).rows[o+1].cells;
            x[0].innerHTML=o+1+".";
            x[4].innerHTML="<Input type='button' name='delete"+o+"' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\","+(o+1)+");' />";
        }

}

function con(){
    var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to make the changes ?");
    if(con){
        document.getElementById('yn').value = "yes";
    }else{
        document.getElementById('yn').value = "no";
    }
}
```

Comment: This should just work. What errors do you get?

Comment: Is it possible someone else is defining a `window.onload` after you?

Comment: @putvande I don't get any errors it just won't write "hello" on my page

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I don't think so

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: It should work though, you much have problems elsewhere on the page, if you want to show us the whole page, im sure we'll help out.. Working Example http://jsfiddle.net/vE4Wa/

Comment: Your browser probably has "developer tools", which have a "javascript console" where errors are logged. Do you see any?

Comment: try replacing the `document.write` with an `alert`. Maybe the "hello" is written, but you just don't see it.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do.

A `document.write` after the page has rendered, will cause the **page contents to be destroyed and replaced** with something new.  BTW, you are better off forgetting that `document.write` even exists.

Comment: @MissChetanGawai aghh , thats weird . thanks for testing it :)

Comment: @HansKesting if i place the document write before the function i can see it printed out

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I was trying to see if it goes into the function or not .

Comment: `alert`, `console.log`, or even `debugger` is a far better choice. If you use the last two under IE, make sure your developer tools are open.

Comment: @HansKesting actually Hans i got this error [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery-2.0.3.js, line 0)

Comment: @DanaVaziri - so that particular jQuery file could not be found. Try and fix that first (remove the reference if you don't need it, else point to the correct file)

Answer (score 1):

The piece of code you supplied is correct.
See JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yh7tB/

However, there might be a couple of reasons that might prevent your function to be executed.

1. Some other javascript code in the page has syntax errors, so javascript interpreter stops processing more script
2. Some other guy overrided `window.onload` function after you, so your method is not executed at all
3. Javascript is disabled on your browser
4. The text is written to a non-visible part of the page, so you don't see it but it exists.

etc.

To be precise and detect the problem accurately, you need to supply more information regarding the issue.

Comment: or 4. the text is written to a non-visible part of the page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Hans. I have added your suggestion as 4th item ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace with below code, its working..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

        document.write("hello");
        er = "";
        var res_name = "";
        var res_des = "";
        var res_price = "";
        var errorno = "";
        document.write(res_price);
        if (errorno > 0) {
            alert("Please enter a correct price for item number : " + errorno);
        }
        for (var p = 1; p <= er + 1; p++) {

            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            // create a row element
            var row = document.createElement("tr");

            // add the row to the table
            table.appendChild(row);

            var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

            // get the select element
            var dropdown = row.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
            // get the current total of dropdowns in the table
            total = (table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length) - 1;

            if (p == er + 1) {
                for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = p;
                    } else if (i == 1) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='name" + p + "' size=30  />";
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='des" + p + "' size=50  />";
                    } else if (i == 3) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='number' name='price" + p + "'  />";
                    } else if (i == 4) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='submit' value='Save'  />";
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
                    //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
                    if (i == 0) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = p + ".";
                    } else if (i == 1) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='name" + p + "' size=30 value='" + res_name[p] + "' />";
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='des" + p + "' size=50 value='" + res_des[p] + "' />";
                    } else if (i == 3) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='number' name='price" + p + "' value='" + res_price[p] + "' />";
                    } else if (i == 4) {
                        newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='button' name='delete" + p + "' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\"," + p + ");' />";
                    }
                }
            }
            document.getElementById('total').value = p;
        }
    };
    function addRowEntry(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        // create a row element
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        // add the row to the table
        table.appendChild(row);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        // get the select element
        var dropdown = row.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
        // get the current total of dropdowns in the table
        total = (table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length) - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            //newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            if (i == 0) {
                newcell.innerHTML = total + ".";
            } else if (i == 1) {
                newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='name" + total + "' size=30  />";
            } else if (i == 2) {
                newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='text' name='des" + total + "' size=50  />";
            } else if (i == 3) {
                newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='number' name='price" + total + "'  />";
            } else if (i == 4) {
                newcell.innerHTML = "<Input type='button' name='delete" + i + "' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\"," + i + ");' />";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID, po) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        table.deleteRow(po);
        document.getElementById('total').value = (document.getElementById('total').value);
        var count = (document.getElementById('total').value) - 1;
        for (var o = 0 ; o <= count ; o++) {

            var x = document.getElementById(tableID).rows[o + 1].cells;
            x[0].innerHTML = o + 1 + ".";
            x[4].innerHTML = "<Input type='button' name='delete" + o + "' value='Delete row' onClick='deleteRow(\"myTable\"," + (o + 1) + ");' />";
        }

    }

    function con() {
        var conf = confirm("Are you sure you want to make the changes ?");
        if (con) {
            document.getElementById('yn').value = "yes";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('yn').value = "no";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: It's still not working i get this error [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (jquery-2.0.3.js, line 0)

Comment: Where are you using this code?..In dotnet webpage or php?..@DanaVaziri

Comment: In PHP , sure how shall i send it to you?